# Tags from http://xmlns.jcp.org namespace do not render, while http://java.sun.com/jsf work fine

Tags: jsf, facelets, xml-namespaces

I have this:

```
<html 
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
>
<h:selectOneRadio>
    <f:selectItem value="1" itemValue="1" itemLabel="123"/>
    <f:selectItem value="2" itemValue="2" itemLabel="321"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

And I get this:

```
<f:selectItem value="1" itemValue="1" itemLabel="123"></f:selectItem>
<f:selectItem value="2" itemValue="2" itemLabel="321"></f:selectItem>
<select name="j_idt5" size="1"></select>
```

Why are `xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"` tags not rendered?

I'm using JBoss AS 7 on Netbeans 7.3.

Comment: Looks like the problem is you're not using JSF 2.2, so you have to define the namespace as `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The new XML namespace domain `http://xmlns.jcp.org` in JSF taglib URIs is introduced in JSF 2.2 which is part of Java EE 7. JBoss AS 7 as being a Java EE 6 compliant application server does not ship with JSF 2.2 bundled, but with JSF 2.1. Therefore the new XML namespace domain does not work at all. Also the new JSF 2.2 specific features such as passthrough elements and attributes won't work at all.

You need to use the JSF 2.1 compatible XML namespace domain `http://java.sun.com`. Here's the complete set:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
```

I'm not sure why you attempted to use the new JSF 2.2 XML namespaces. Perhaps you incorrectly read a JSF 2.2 targeted tutorial (e.g. [Oracle Java EE 7 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-intro.htm)) instead of a JSF 2.0/2.1 targeted one (e.g. [Oracle Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html)). Pay carefully attention that the versions match.

If you really intend to use JSF 2.2 on a JBoss server, then you should basically be upgrading the old JBoss AS 7 to its Java EE 7 compatible successor [WildFly 8](http://www.wildfly.org/). Alternatively, manually upgrade the bundled JSF libraries of JBoss AS 7 to a newer version as instructed here: [Upgrade JSF / Mojarra in JBoss AS / EAP / WildFly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085717/upgrade-and-use-mojarra-as-the-jsf-implementation-with-jboss-server).

Comment: This helped! Thank You very much!
I'm using NetBeans 7.3 and it add 'wrong' namespace automatically. I don't know why it imposes new beta jsf 2.2 instead of the old.

Answer (score -2):

please look in WEB-INF Folder
there is web.xml
if there is no such file ,jsf is not renders 
many maven archetype for jboss have not this file 
create this file in  WEB-INF Folder
sample:

﻿
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

```
<display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>

<!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/hello.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You're confusing the current question with a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112946/jsf-returns-blank-unparsed-page-with-plain-raw-xhtml-xml-el-source-instead-of-re Basically, you posted this "answer" to a wrong question. By the way, having 4 loose servlet mappings is unnecessary. You can have just only 1 with 4 URL patterns. Even then, having 4 URL patterns is ridiculous and not SEO friendly. Just stick to only one, `*.xhtml`.