# ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined

Tags: maven, jsf, wildfly

I'm migrating a JSF project using Mojarra 2.2.8 from GlassFish to WildFly. I'm using Maven to manage dependencies and I have not physically added libraries in the server folder. On WildFly I get the below exception during deployment. From what I understand, there is a conflict between different JSF implementations.

```
11:47:55,630 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-3) Unable to process annotations for url, vfs:/C:/utils/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/cursus-management.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-5.0.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml.  Reason: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
11:47:55,631 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-3) : java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:88) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(URLJarFile.java:221) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(URLJarFile.java:216) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:215) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:71) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.processClasspath(JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.java:166) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.getAnnotatedClasses(JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.DelegatingAnnotationProvider.getAnnotatedClasses(DelegatingAnnotationProvider.java:85) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:932) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:884) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:383) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:221) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:86)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:71)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]

11:47:55,635 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-3) Unable to process annotations for url, vfs:/C:/utils/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/cursus-management.war/WEB-INF/lib/omnifaces-1.8.1.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml.  Reason: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
11:47:55,635 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-3) : java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:88) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(URLJarFile.java:221) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(URLJarFile.java:216) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:215) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:71) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.processClasspath(JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.java:166) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.getAnnotatedClasses(JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.DelegatingAnnotationProvider.getAnnotatedClasses(DelegatingAnnotationProvider.java:85) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:932) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:884) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:383) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:221) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:86)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:71)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]

11:47:55,639 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-3) Unable to process annotations for url, vfs:/C:/utils/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments/cursus-management.war/WEB-INF/lib/prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml.  Reason: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
11:47:55,639 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-3) : java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:88) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(URLJarFile.java:221) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(URLJarFile.java:216) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:215) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:71) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.processClasspath(JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.java:166) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.getAnnotatedClasses(JavaClassScanningAnnotationScanner.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.DelegatingAnnotationProvider.getAnnotatedClasses(DelegatingAnnotationProvider.java:85) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:932) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:884) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:383) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:221) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:86)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:71)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]

11:47:56,759 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-3) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:422) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:378) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:437) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:221) [jsf-impl-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:86)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:71)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]

11:47:56,760 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./cursus-management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./cursus-management: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:86)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:71)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:280)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:422)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:378)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:437)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:221)
    ... 9 more

11:47:56,767 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "cursus-management.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./cursus-management" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./cursus-management: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined"}}
11:47:57,205 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "cursus-management.war" (runtime-name : "cursus-management.war")
11:47:57,206 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./cursus-management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./cursus-management: Failed to start service
```

pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <jsf-version>2.2.8</jsf-version>
    <org.springframework.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <org.slf4j.version>1.7.7</org.slf4j.version>
    <org.apache.cxf.version>3.0.2</org.apache.cxf.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- omnifaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- EL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <!-- PrimeFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PrettyFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ocpsoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>prettyfaces-jsf2</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SLF4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log Back -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CXF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>cursus-management</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly install and configure JSF libraries via Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081234/how-to-properly-install-and-configure-jsf-libraries-via-maven)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *From what I understand, there is a conflict between different JSF implementations*

This kind of problems are indeed typical when there are multiple different versioned JSF API classes in the runtime classpath.

In your particular case, you're telling Maven to bundle JSF (and other Java EE related artifacts!) libraries in WAR's `/WEB-INF/lib`. This is not right. When targeting a Java EE compliant server (read: not Tomcat), those libraries (JSF, Servlet, JSTL, EL, etc) are supposed to be **already** provided by the target server itself. So you should put them to `<provided>` scope in Maven.

You'd better replace the below

```
<properties>
    ...
    <jsf-version>2.2.8</jsf-version>
    ...
</properties>

<!-- JSF -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jsf-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${jsf-version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Servlet -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- EL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency> -->
```

by

```
<properties>
    ...
    <javaee-version>7.0</javaee-version>
    ...
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>${javaee.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you'd like to individually upgrade JSF version in WildFly, then head to this answer: [Upgrade JSF / Mojarra in JBoss AS / EAP / WildFly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085717/upgrade-and-use-mojarra-as-the-jsf-implementation-with-jboss-server/).

That it worked in GlassFish is likely because the declared versions coincidentally exactly match the GlassFish-provided ones (but you would still risk to run into unexplainable `ClassCastExceptions` on Java EE related classes during runtime).

Comment: replacing dependence with that of javaee-web-ap, it caused  Maven Dependency Problem

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually described the problem instead of overgeneralizing it by the single word "Problem".

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax:javaee-web-api:jar:${javaee.version}: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer javax:javaee-web-api:pom:${javaee.version} from http://repository.primefaces.org was cached in the local repository...

Comment: So you didn't set the `${javaee.version}` as indicated in the answer? Why not?

Comment: @BaluscC you're right, I'm sorry, it's a stupid mistake

Answer (score -1):

Go to right click to your proyect and go to Properties->Project Facets->Java Server Faces and change
from: "Jsf 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2.0)" 
to "Jsf 2.0 (Mojarra 2.0.3-FCS)"

Comment: Very, very bad suggestion. If you think otherwise, please explain in detail why you think it is a good solution