# rich:dataScroller - scrollListener action method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I am running into an issue migrating RF 3.3.3 DataTable to RF 4.3.3-Final, I am using rich:dataScroller for serverside pagination whereby the scrollListener attribute fires backingbean method to fetch next batch of results.

So far I have updated rich:dataScroller and scrollListener names to match the RF4 spec

```
                <rich:dataScroller page="#{viewSignatures.signaturesTable.currentPage}" 
                    scrollListener="#{viewSignatures.actionOnPageChange}" maxPages="5" 
                    fastControls="show" stepControls="hide" renderIfSinglePage="false">
                </rich:dataScroller>
```

Then on the action method I added the DataScrollEvent argument (not sure if this is necessary though?)

```
@Override
    public void actionOnPageChange(DataScrollEvent event) {  
        String val = event.getNewScrolVal();  
        log.info(val);  
        return val;  
    }
```

When I change pages I get the following exception:

```
17:32:59,158 ERROR [org.jboss.seam.exception.Exceptions] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-9) handled and logged exception: javax.servlet.ServletException
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.18.Final.jar:2.1.18.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:73) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:67)
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:48)
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.handleRequest(ClusteredSessionValve.java:134) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.JvmRouteValve.invoke(JvmRouteValve.java:92) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.LockingValve.invoke(LockingValve.java:64) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:488) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:420) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.richfaces.taglib.MethodExpressionScrollListener.processDataScroll(MethodExpressionScrollListener.java:27) [richfaces-components-ui-4.3.3.Final.jar:4.3.3.Final]
    at org.richfaces.event.DataScrollEvent.processListener(DataScrollEvent.java:83) [richfaces-components-api-4.3.3.Final.jar:4.3.3.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:775) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.18.Final.jar:2.1.18.Final]
    at org.richfaces.component.AbstractDataScroller.broadcast(AbstractDataScroller.java:206) [richfaces-components-ui-4.3.3.Final.jar:4.3.3.Final]
    at org.richfaces.component.RowKeyContextEventWrapper.broadcast(RowKeyContextEventWrapper.java:104) [richfaces-components-ui-4.3.3.Final.jar:4.3.3.Final]
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.broadcast(UIDataAdaptor.java:448) [richfaces-components-ui-4.3.3.Final.jar:4.3.3.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.18.Final.jar:2.1.18.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.18.Final.jar:2.1.18.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.1.18-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.18-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.18-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.18.Final.jar:2.1.18.Final]
    ... 32 more

17:32:59,207 ERROR [org.jboss.seam.exception.Exceptions] (ajp-localhost/127.0.0.1:8009-9) handled and logged exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter message is null
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.notNull(Util.java:299) [jsf-impl-2.1.18-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.addMessage(FacesContextImpl.java:492) [jsf-impl-2.1.18-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesMessages.beforeRenderResponse(FacesMessages.java:45) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforeRenderResponse(SeamPhaseListener.java:488) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforeServletPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:147) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforePhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:117) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228) [jsf-impl-2.1.18-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99) [jsf-impl-2.1.18-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.18-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.18.Final.jar:2.1.18.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:73) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:67)
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:48)
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.handleRequest(ClusteredSessionValve.java:134) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.JvmRouteValve.invoke(JvmRouteValve.java:92) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.LockingValve.invoke(LockingValve.java:64) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:488) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:420) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
```

The 'NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter message is null' part of the exception is then repeated 20-30 times resulting in a redirect loop

Comment: Looks like an RF bug; post the full stacktrace here

Comment: Based on RichFaces source code, the NPE is caused because the `MethodExpression` is `null`. Upon further inspection it appears that the `scrollListener` expects a `void` method. However, you've there a method which returns `String` (which is only typical for action methods returning a navigation outcome, not for listener methods). Try making it a `void` method and let me know if that indeed solves the problem.

Comment: @BalusC Good spot! Unfortunately though after changing the method to void it still throws the same exception (with or without the DataScrollEvent arg)

Comment: Another probable cause would be that `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()` returned `null` in there. But that would be a rather serious problem which should have more consequences than only this. Are you capable of putting a debug breakpoint there so you can check which of the two is `null`? The `FacesContext` or `MethodExpression`? In any case, do you see chance to upgrade JBoss AS bundled Mojarra 2.1.18 to something newer? It's currently already at 2.1.29. You can find JBoss AS upgrade instructions in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17085879 Or perhaps give WildFly 8.2 a try.

Comment: @BalusC thank you for your input, turns out I had PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING disabled from a previous workaround causing the problem. I will attempt the Mojarra update soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had partial state saving disabled due to a previous workaround, enabling it solved the issue

javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING
    true