# After switching @ManagedBean to @Named: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'person' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, managed-bean, glassfish-4.1

I am just testing out this JSF page, so I don't set the `action` attribute in the `<h:commandButton/>`. This is a very simple form with 3 input boxes for First Name, Last Name, and Email, and one button called Save. Every time I click that button, I receive this error

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @19,106 value="#{person.firstName}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'person' resolved to null
```

but if I annotate my JavaBean `@ManagedBean`, then the form go through just fine, but every time I switch back to using `@Named` Bean, I receive that error again. I have tried some of the suggestions I found on this site such as restarting the server, checking the presence of the getters, but those did not help.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Simple Form Created Using Facelets</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:messages/>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="rightColumn, leftColumn">

                <h:outputLabel for="firstName" value="First Name:" />
                <h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{person.firstName}"
                             label="First Name"/>

                <h:outputLabel for="lastName" value="Last Name:" />
                <h:inputText id="lastName" value="#{person.lastName}" label="Last Name"/>

                <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Email:"/>
                <h:inputText id="email" value="#{person.email}" label="Email" />

                <h:panelGroup />
                <h:commandButton value="Submit"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaBean class

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Person {

    private String firstName = "empty";
    private String lastName = "empty";
    private String email = "empty";

    public void Person() {}

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

This is the `web.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, it is GlassFish 4.1

Comment: Should indeed just work out the box in a Java EE 7 container. Do you have a `/WEB-INF/beans.xml`?

Comment: No, I don't. That's what I thought too

Comment: The `RequestScoped` should be `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped` for `CDI`. Do not mix the `JSF` scope and `CDI` scope.

Comment: @Charlee That's correct (I already wanted to side-remark this in my answer, if any), but this is not the cause of that problem. A scope-less CDI bean defaults in a JSF page to request scope already.

Comment: @BalusC I totally agree with you.

Comment: @BalusC,  why do I need the `beans.xml` file to get CDI Bean to work ?

Comment: It's likely another GF4 bug. Have you tried removing all the config files `web.xml`, `faces-config.xml` and `beans.xml` so that bare defaults are used?

Comment: @BalusC No I have not, I tried creating the `faces-config.xml` file, but it did not solve the problem until I added the `beans.xml`, but if I removed the `beans.xml`, I got that error

Comment: Do you have any JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: @BalusC I don't even have that `lib` folder, I just added the JSF jar file by right clicking the `Libraries` section in Netbeans, but that did not make any difference since GlassFish has that jar toos

Comment: You should indeed not have any.

Comment: I had been using GlassFish Server 4.0 for a long time until I upgraded GlassFish to 4.1 a few months ago and I have been using GlassFish Server 4.1 since then. No `beans.xml` was ever needed explicitly in both 4.0 and 4.1. (The application has already traversed through all Mojarra 2.2.x versions alternatively - starting from Mojarra 2.2.0 to 2.3.0-m01).

Comment: @BalusC @Tiny I don't know what is going with my GS, the standard resource location is not working for me either. I test a dummy script file, put it in a `scripts` subfolder under the `resources` folder, and the `resources` folder is under `META-INF` and then at the application root using `<h:outputScript />`, but I keep getting `Unable to find resource `. My structure is like this, `JavaServerFaces` is the parent directory where all other folders are located, then in it, there is the `resources` folder, inside the `resources` folder is the `scripts` sub folder where the script file is stored

Comment: Slip the `resources` folder directly into the web application root. (`META-INF` is meant for a standalone module in a separately packaged JAR file which finally ends up in `/WEB-INF/lib` in the associated WAR).

Comment: @Tiny Yeah, I have done that too, I have the `resources` folder in the `JavaServerFaces` parent folder, and the `resources` folder is then sub-divided into smaller folders for better resource organizing, in this case, I hate the `scripts` sub-folder which contains a dummy javascript file. Aghh, so frustrating, I don't know what is wrong with my GS

Comment: You may want to look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11988418/1391249) answer in case you might accidentally be missing something. Perhaps, something along the line `<h:outputScript  library="..." name="..." />` is going wrong. And please do not forget to hard-deploy the application at least once after these changes have been made. If the problem still persists, you may want to put a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best answer to my problem [LINK](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations)
. Also, cdi-1.2 jar file is not available in GS 4.1 for some reason, that is why the package javax.enterprise.* was not present in my Netbeans, I had to manually download that jar from http://cdi-spec.org/. Now everything works fine including DI. And I did not have to create any configuration files to get it to work either.

Comment: It is available in GlassFish 4.1 as obvious which is already a Java EE compliant-container but those classes are packaged under a library named `Java EE 7 API` Library containing a single large JAR file named `javaee-api-7.0.jar`. You can add that library to the compile-time class-path of your web module as and when required. There is no need to add the CDI library separately as needed in bare-bones Servlet containers like Apache Tomcat, Eclipse Jetty.

Comment: The reason CDI 1.2 jar isn't available in GlassFish 4.1 is because it packages CDI 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that your using JSF annotations instead of CDI annoations. To fix that, change the import:

```
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
```

to

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
```

However, another solution is to create a `beans.xml` file.

To do that, create one in the `WEB-INF` folder with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

> The presence of a beans.xml file signals the servlet container that
>   the application uses JSR-299 (Contexts and Dependency Injection) -
>   without it, the application's classes will not be scanned for CDI
>   annotations either and dependency injection will not be performed. If
>   you don't use CDI (e.g. you only use plain JSF managed beans), you
>   don't need beans.xml.

**See also:**

- [Why are there different bean management annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057564/why-are-there-different-bean-management-annotations)

Comment: Uh! Java EE 7 (GlassFish 4.1). `beans.xml` is unnecessary unless explicitly needed.

Comment: Hey, it works. Why is that? Doesn't the Java EE specs state that the configuration files are optional?

Comment: Sorry, I think this is more of a hack rather a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your request scoped annotation from faces to CDI.

The reason being is if you look at your annotations

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
```

None of these are CDI "bean defining annotations" so if you're using `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"` it's not going to work for you.

Comment: Because it didn't explain anything. Explain how to fish instead of only giving the fish.

Comment: I know the question is old but... In your `beans.xml` change `annotated` to `all`. It should fix the problem, at least it did with my error.