# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FLOW at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension.<clinit>

Tags: jsf, jboss7.x, jsf-2.2, faces-flow, nosuchfieldexception

I began to learn JBoss today and i'm having some problems.

When I run the project, gave this error:

I am using JBoss, Primefaces and JSF. IDE: Eclipse

```
16:38:39,268 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Teste.war"
16:38:39,831 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
16:38:39,832 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
16:38:39,833 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
16:38:39,834 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
16:38:39,904 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment Teste.war
16:38:39,908 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Teste.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Teste.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "Teste.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FLOW
    at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension.<clinit>(FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadExtension(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:117)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:86)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more

16:38:39,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "Teste.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Teste.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Teste.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"Teste.war\""}}
16:38:39,935 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Teste.war in 12ms
16:38:39,938 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Teste.Teste (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Teste.Teste.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Teste.Teste.Validator] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Teste.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Teste.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "Teste.war"

16:38:39,941 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Teste.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Teste.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"Teste.war\""}}}}
```

Comment: Problem suggests you manually added JSF 2.2 to WAR instead of upgrading JBoss own JSF 2.1? And thus you run JSF 2.1 and 2.2 simultaneously which would only conflict each other. This is then likely the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17085717

Comment: thanks for help, i did this and got a bigger error log :/. Want to see it?

Comment: What's the bottommost root cause? (just copypaste type, message and 1st line here)

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14566409/

Comment: So you just got [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/faces/spi/InjectionProvider](http://google.com/search?q=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:+com/sun/faces/spi/InjectionProvider)? Well, apparently upgrade still done bad. Perhaps you forgot removing JSF from WAR?