# How to install one jar variant of JSF 2.3 (javax.faces.jar) on WildFly

Tags: jsf, wildfly, jsf-2.3

I want to use the JSF 2.3 on my application, but WildFly uses the 2 JAR variant for 2.2.

Oracle said here https://javaserverfaces.java.net/2.3/download.html that won't release a 2.3 2 JAR variant.

Comment: And WildFly cannot use a one jar variant? Is that stated somewhere?

Comment: `javax.faces.jar` is meant for GlassFish only. The rest is similar  http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2014/10/jsf-22-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-wildfly.html#UpgradeMojarraInWildFly, http://stackoverflow.com/a/17085879/1391249

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the manual procedure:

1. Extract `javax.faces.jar` with a ZIP tool. You'll get 3 folders `com`, `javax`, `META-INF` 
   <sub>(NOTE: in some versions you'll also see a `jsf.js` file in the root, but this is a mistake, you should ignore it, it's already located in `META-INF/resources/javax.faces`)</sub>
2. Pack `com` and `META-INF` folders into `jsf-impl.jar` with a ZIP tool.
3. Then, delete all files/subfolders in `META-INF` **except** of `MANIFEST.MF`.
4. Pack `javax` and `META-INF` folders into `jsf-api.jar` with a ZIP tool.
5. Continue here with those JARs: [Upgrade JSF / Mojarra in JBoss AS / EAP / WildFly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085717/upgrade-jsf-mojarra-in-jboss-as-eap-wildfly).

---

For the interested, JBoss AS and WildFly has internally a modular separation of Java EE based API and impl files. The separated JAR files `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar` are still needed. The reason is not really technical, but just an extra service to force developers programming against the right libraries. Only the API modules are exposed during compile time (usually, via the IDE-integrated plugin which adds them to "build path"). This should avoid starters accidentally finding, importing and using implementation classes such as those in `com.sun.faces.*` package.

Already since version 1.x, the JSF implementation Mojarra was composed of two JAR files: `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar`. The API JAR contained the `javax.faces.*` classes and the implementation JAR contained the `com.sun.faces.*` classes. Since the change of the build system conform Java EE Maven rules, both the API and implementation classes were merged into a single `javax.faces.jar` file, see also [issue 2028](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2028) (started with Mojarra 2.1.6 at Dec 2011). Since Mojarra 2.3, the separated JAR files are not built anymore.