# JSF 2.3 on EAP 7

Tags: jboss-eap-7, jsf-2.3

I would like to upgrade to JSF 2.3 on an Jboss EAP 7.

I followed this guide:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JSF+Configuration#JSFConfiguration-ConfiguringaJSFapptouseanondefaultJSFimplementation

I splitted the JSF 2.3 jar following this guide:

[How to install one jar variant of JSF (javax.faces.jar) on WildFly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899887/how-to-install-one-jar-variant-of-jsf-javax-faces-jar-on-wildfly)

However, when I start EAP 7 I get this error:

```
2017-04-30 12:55:00,280 WARN  (JSFDependencyProcessor.java:75) = WFLYJSF0005: Unknown JSF version 'mojarra-2.3.0'.  Default version 'mojarra-2.3.0' will be used instead.
2017-04-30 12:55:00,281 ERROR (ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955) = MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."monitoring.war".DEPENDENCIES: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."monitoring.war".DEPENDENCIES: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment "monitoring.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJSF0014: Default JSF implementation slot 'mojarra-2.3.0' is invalid
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFDependencyProcessor.deploy(JSFDependencyProcessor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
```

Does anybody successfully upgraded EAP 7 to JSF 2.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a mistake by misreading the place where to put all the needed jars.

For instance, the module `javax.faces.api` I put in the folder:

`EAP_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/javax/faces/api/JSF_IMPL`

Instead, it needed to go to:

`EAP_HOME/modules/javax/faces/api/JSF_IMPL`.

It was specified like this in the guide, but for other modules (Oracle JDBC Driver...) I needed to put stuff directly under the base folder. Apparently, for JSF, this needs to be in the root of the modules folder...

Now it is loaded correctly and, when I use `LOG.info(FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion());` it prints `2017-05-02 08:59:47,872 INFO  (Web.java:66) = 2.3.0`