# JSF 2.3 first time, viewScoped managedBean not found

Tags: jsf, cdi, propertynotfoundexception

Hi i have this kind of error when i try to click on button "Submit"

```
An Error Occurred:
/mail.xhtml @14,72 value="#{emailBean.email}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'emailBean' resolved to null
- Stack Trace
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /mail.xhtml @14,72 value="#{emailBean.email}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'emailBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1122)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:1030)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1334)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1298)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:269)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1298)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1298)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1332)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'emailBean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:173)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:85)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:201)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:104)
    ... 51 more
```

I use JSF 2.3, use @Named instead @ManagedBean and CDI for all Scopes except for ViewScope:

```
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


mail.xhtml:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
>
<h:head>
    <title>check mail validation</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputLabel value="E-mail:" for="emailId"/>
            <h:inputText id="nameemailId" value="#{emailBean.email}" validator="emailValidator"/>
            <h:message for="emailId"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{emailBean.sendEmail()}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class EmailBean implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3247395658736113405L;

    private Email email;


    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize(){
        this.email = new Email("prova");
    }

    public EmailBean(Email email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Email getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(Email email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void sendEmail(){
        System.out.println("Email sended");
    }
}
```

beans.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_3.xsd"
           version="2.0" bean-discovery-mode="all">
    </beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bluelotussoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>scope-examples-jsf-2-3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>scope-examples-jsf-2-3</name>
    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                            <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I deploy on Wildfly 10 and i replace jsf-api and jsf-impl reading this guides:

```
step 1 (how to packages jars):
```

[How to install one jar variant of JSF (javax.faces.jar) on WildFly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899887/how-to-install-one-jar-variant-of-jsf-javax-faces-jar-on-wildfly)

```
step 2 (how to install):
```

[Upgrade JSF / Mojarra in JBoss AS / EAP / WildFly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085717/upgrade-jsf-mojarra-in-jboss-as-eap-wildfly)

thanks you

Roberto

Comment: offtopic: start using jsf 2.2+ namespaces everywhere!!!

Answer (score -2):

SAME ERROR IN ANOTHER QUESTION
There should be a bean.xml
and
a faces-config.xml for faces application (JSF)
[Changing faces-config.xml from 2.2 to 2.3 causes javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682309/changing-faces-config-xml-from-2-2-to-2-3-causes-javax-el-propertynotfoundexcept)

ALSO
Of the error and the property value being null.
check the bean "state" configuration session or page... (should be session)
if it not session then it will be dropped each time a request is made.
It is a mapping to the bean class gone wrong for the error
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /mail.xhtml @14,72 value="#{emailBean.email}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'emailBean' resolved to null

==== old info - 
I believe your faces navigation rules for JSF configuration from and to a page should have names and  should be clarified in your web.xml

Here is a link to "simple" a tutorial page for a J2EE server for JSF to explain.

http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jsf-managedBean-and-ejb/README.html

(note careful of the call syntax in the code too)

Comment: That is a very prehistoric example and should **NOT** be used when doing JSF 2.3 things!!!

Comment: nope. I miss a default constructor or i add a constructor with one parameter that is not a bean. So injection failes...

Comment: what does faces-config.xml and bean.xml have for mapping to the emailbean (too right -1 to me)