# "TypeError: partialResponse is undefined" in h:inputFile when use <f:ajax>

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I want to upload a file using ajax. But in doing so I get the following error in the browser console when i select the file.

TypeError: partialResponse is undefined in jsf.js.

It not happens with other inputs with ajax, only with inputFile.

[Picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goNoA.png)

Recently i update to jsf 2.2.14 in a JBOSS EAP 6.3. The servlet is 3.0 (i checked this in the web.xml).

To upload file i follow these example: https://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/jsf22-file-upload/

This is in the xhtml:

```
            <h:form id="formTest" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{manejador.maestroFormularios.maestroArchivos.archivoTemporal}" >
                    <f:ajax execute="@this" render=":formTest"/>
                </h:inputFile>
                <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{manejador.maestroFormularios.maestroArchivos.cargarArchivoEnLista()}"/>
            </h:form>
```

In the backing bean i use archivoTemporal of type Part:

```
public class MaestroArchivos implements Serializable {

private Part archivoTemporal;
```

Comment: Did it work before you upgraded something? Please edit your question to form a [mcve]

Comment: @Selaron recently just finished editing again.

Comment: Post the bean as explained in [Stackoverflow's JSF info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). And where is the `h:form`?

Comment: @Selaron ready again.

Comment: Did you follow these steps and also cleaned/refreshed browser cache? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085717/upgrade-jsf-mojarra-in-jboss-as-eap-wildfly

Comment: Yes, i follow these steps to configure jboss 6.3 and refreshed the browser cache. So far i use jsf 2.2 in two enviroments the only problem is with the file upload.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by removing the nested `f:ajax` from the `h:inputFile`. And I also added the following code in the web.xml file in the servlet tag.

```
<multipart-config>
        <location>/tmp</location>
        <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Sure you did not also remove the `f:ajax` from inside the `h:inputFile`?

Comment: I even think the multpart config does not play any role in **this** error. It might have been needed to get it to work fully, but not for this error

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was permission issue.

Apache Tomcat 8.x

```
                                                    your [.war]
root   root /path/to/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT/
```

Tomcat runs with `userowner` user, but `ROOT` path was `root`

```
sudo chown userowner /path/to/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT[.war]/ -R
sudo chgrp usergroup /path/to/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT[.war]/ -R
```

Comment: But you most likely had an explicit java error in the server too?

Comment: @Kukeltje Nope, there is no any error in backend. JSF returns XML response, but `partialResponse` is missing.

Comment: I find it hard to understand that this permission thing would cause this behaviour. What is your JSF version and impl?

Comment: @Kukeltje jsf version 2.2.8. We cannot update jsf version for possible conflict with Spring-mvc + spring data + etc...

Comment: I'm not saying you should upgrade (and spring-mvc and jsf are btw 'competing' frameworks) rather curious on how this rights thing can cause this error (unless you write the uploaded files to your webapp folder)