# How to pack my own JSF version into application war archive deployed at WildFly server?

Tags: jsf, wildfly

It's clear to me how to install my own JSF version at WildFly server ([Upgrade JSF / Mojarra in JBoss AS / EAP / WildFly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17085879/802058), many thx to BalusC) but is it possible to pack my own JSF version along with my application **into war archive** deployed at WildFly server? If so, how to do that? Is it enough to put (e.g. https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/releases/download/2.3.15/jakarta.faces-2.3.15.jar) into `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the application? Thx.

Comment: You need that JAR file and everything it depends on.

Comment: What do you need from that version that's not in 2.3.14? WildFly 23 is on 2.3.14 https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-14401.

Comment: The mentioned JSF version was only an example. The question is how to do that in general if possible.